# errorを表示させたいのに、警告でperrorではないかと表示される

Tags: c

stackが空状態ならエラーを出すように組んだんですが、警告されます。
原因などがあるのでしょうか？

```
if(isStackEmpty()){
    error("stackが空状態です");
    exit(1);
```

Comment: このヘルプ記事[再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)を参考に、他の人が問題を再現・調査出来るような最小限のソースコードを提示してみてください。あと使用しているOS,コンパイラの種別・版数やコンパイル時オプション等、そして表示されたエラーの全文を過不足無く追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

コードが一部分しか提示されていないので憶測を含みますが、少なくともよく使われる stdio.h の中に `error` 関数は定義されていないので、エラー時にメッセージを出すのが目的であれば、コンパイラが警告を出している通り `perror` を使うべきなのではないでしょうか？

**参考:**
[標準Cライブラリ | 入出力 stdio.h | Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A8%99%E6%BA%96C%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA#%E5%85%A5%E5%87%BA%E5%8A%9B_stdio.h)

(名前に "errror" を含むもののみ抜粋)

> - ferror — エラー表示子の判定
> - perror — 標準エラー出力へのエラーメッセージの出力

Answer (score 0):

下記サンプルコード（要は `error()` の先行宣言なし＝バグっているというか古いスタイル）

```
#include <stdio.h>
#if 0
#include <stdlib.h>
void error(const char* message) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", message);
    exit(0);
}
#endif
int main() {
    error("stackoverflow");
}
```

を [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) gcc-10.2.0 でコンパイルしてみます

```
$ gcc -c perrortest.c 
perrortest.c: In function 'main':
perrortest.c:10:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'error'; did you mean 'perror'? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   10 |  error("stackoverflow");
      |  ^~~~~
      |  perror
$
```

警告内容をオレオレ意訳すると

- 標準関数 `perror` ときわめて類似した名前の `error` という関数が宣言なしに使われているが、これは `perror` の書き間違いではないか

`#if 0` を `#if 1` にすると `error()` 関数は使用前に原型宣言されており、かつ宣言通りに使われているので `perror` の間違いではないかという警告は出なくなります。

ということであなたのソースコードが断片的過ぎて断言できませんが `error()` 関数の原型宣言を追加してやれば警告は消えるでしょう、という回答になります。